# Why did Peter dedicate his first book to those who are 'strangers'? (1Peter1.1) Was Peter different to the other apostles, and aware of it?

Tags: acts, law, history, peter, linguistics

Does the linguistic trope 'strangers' hold implications regarding inner nature of certain biblical characters? If Jesus blessed Peter could he have opened Peter's eyes to his (base) nature in need of redemption, as implied by 'strangers'? (ie of the line of Cain)

Answer (score 3):

My answer is going to be short and to the point. Peter is addressing believers, chiefly Jewish Christians, scattered throughout five Roman provinces of Asia Minor. These Christians were being persecuted.

Peter called them "strangers" (parepidemois, sojourners) because earth is but their temporary home; their permanent abode is heaven. The term "scattered" suggest they were clustered in little church groups here and there.

Notice at verse 2 the believers are "elect" (eklektois, chosen) according to the foreknowledge of God the Father through sanctification of the Holy Spirit.

Comment: Thanks for that - I was expecting this answer...but what if one looks a little deeper at Peters character, and the duality of the way Jesus viewed him..?